# How to insert time format in form designed using PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to insert time format(12:45) in a form designed by using php language.I want to insert time format in the text field.
my database table name is store_login_time. Table field is same "time".

```
<input type="text" name="time" id="time" value="<?php echo $time?>"/>
```

here php script is used to store value in database. My database table name is "login_time"
and table field is "time" format type is "TIME"
Please help me I am poor in php.

Comment: To help you, you need to give us some more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can display time using

```
<input type ="text" id="time" name="time" value="<?php echo date("h:i:s A")?>"/>
```

SQL Query like

```
INSERT INTO login_time(time) VALUES("<?php $_get['time']?>")
```

I think it helps to you.

Comment: Thank you Jalpesh it works it gives the current time in the text field.Thank you once again..

Answer (score 0):

You can get time Format by using this:

```
<input type="time" name="time"/>
```